# Unknown error 504 when connecting Source : MongoDB to Destination: Postgres on Airbyte

Tags: mongodb, airbyte, mongo-connector

New to Airbyte
Airbyte on Docker on Ec2
Source : MongoDb
Destination : Postgres
When creating the connection it throws the below error : [504 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljtts.png)

The same connection working fine on my local Airbyte setup.

Been stuck on this for a week now. Any suggestions?

Tried to increase time out value in airbyte source - monbgoDb config file . It dint work out. Got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by inginx timeout issue. Increased proxy_read_timeout and
proxy_connect_timeout for inginx and this got resolved.